# Move Product Description php - Probs

Tags: php, zen-cart

Any help is much appreciated. I have been trying to move the product Description to below the price in zencart, but the description fails to show. The question is where the dickens am I going wrong. Thanks for looking Jon

The line I have moved is:

```
<div class="listingDescription">' . zen_trunc_string(zen_clean_html(stripslashes(zen_get_products_description($listing->fields['products_id'], $_SESSION['languages_id']))), PRODUCT_LIST_DESCRIPTION) . '</div>
```

The original code is:

```
    if (isset($_GET['manufacturers_id'])) {
$lc_text = 'fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' .  (($_GET['manufacturers_id'] > 0 and $_GET['filter_id']) > 0 ?  zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['filter_id']) : ($_GET['cPath'] > 0 ? zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['cPath']) : zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($listing->fields['master_categories_id']))) . '&products_id=' . $listing->fields['products_id']) . '">' . $listing->fields['products_name'] . '' . zen_trunc_string(zen_clean_html(stripslashes(zen_get_products_description($listing->fields['products_id'], $_SESSION['languages_id']))), PRODUCT_LIST_DESCRIPTION) . '' ;
        } else {
          $lc_text = 'fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . (($_GET['manufacturers_id'] > 0 and $_GET['filter_id']) > 0 ?  zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['filter_id']) : ($_GET['cPath'] > 0 ? zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['cPath']) : zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($listing->fields['master_categories_id']))) . '&products_id=' . $listing->fields['products_id']) . '">' . $listing->fields['products_name'] . '' . zen_trunc_string(zen_clean_html(stripslashes(zen_get_products_description($listing->fields['products_id'], $_SESSION['languages_id']))), PRODUCT_LIST_DESCRIPTION) . '';
        }
        break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_MANUFACTURER':
        $lc_align = '';
        $lc_text = 'fields['manufacturers_id']) . '">' . $listing->fields['manufacturers_name'] . '';
        break;
        case 'PRODUCT_LIST_PRICE':
        $lc_price = zen_get_products_display_price($listing->fields['products_id']) . '
';
        $lc_align = 'right';
        $lc_text =  $lc_price;
```

The code I have tried (The page / price shows, but not the product description):

```
        if (isset($_GET['manufacturers_id'])) {
      $lc_text = '<h3 class="itemTitle"><a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($listing->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . (($_GET['manufacturers_id'] > 0 and $_GET['filter_id']) > 0 ?  zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['filter_id']) : ($_GET['cPath'] > 0 ? zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['cPath']) : zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($listing->fields['master_categories_id']))) . '&products_id=' . $listing->fields['products_id']) . '">' . $listing->fields['products_name'] . '</a></h3>' ;
    } else {
      $lc_text = '<h3 class="itemTitle"><a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($listing->fields['products_id']), 'cPath=' . (($_GET['manufacturers_id'] > 0 and $_GET['filter_id']) > 0 ?  zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['filter_id']) : ($_GET['cPath'] > 0 ? zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($_GET['cPath']) : zen_get_generated_category_path_rev($listing->fields['master_categories_id']))) . '&products_id=' . $listing->fields['products_id']) . '">' . $listing->fields['products_name'] . '</a></h3>';
    }
    break;
    case 'PRODUCT_LIST_MANUFACTURER':
    $lc_align = '';
    $lc_text = '<a href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' . $listing->fields['manufacturers_id']) . '">' . $listing->fields['manufacturers_name'] . '</a>';
    break;
    case 'PRODUCT_LIST_PRICE':
    $lc_price = zen_get_products_display_price($listing->fields['products_id']) . '';
    $lc_align = 'right';
    $lc_text =  "<div style='font-size: 22px;'>".$lc_price. "</div>";
    break;
    case 'PRODUCT_LIST_DESCRIPTION':
    $lc_align = '';
    $lc_text = '<div class="listingDescription">' . zen_trunc_string(zen_clean_html(stripslashes(zen_get_products_description($listing->fields['products_id'], $_SESSION['languages_id']))), PRODUCT_LIST_DESCRIPTION) . '<br></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any code. 
Instead, simply change the desired sort order in Admin->Configuration->Product Listing.